# When I use '/js/app.js' on my Laravel view my Bootstrap doesn't load

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade, laravel-mix

I'm using this Laravel View to show a Vue Component, but when I use this on my view, then the Bootstrap doesn't work. How can I solve this problem.

```
<script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

This is my view.

**View**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title')
Brand
@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 product-img mt-3">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="{{ $product->imageUrl }}" alt="First slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="{{ $product->image1 }}" alt="Second slide">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center pt-2">
                <img style="cursor: pointer" data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active img-thumbnail product-image" src="{{ $product->imageUrl }}" alt="">
                <img style="cursor: pointer" data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1" class="img-thumbnail product-image" src="{{ $product->image1 }}" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 product-info product mt-5 mb-2">
        <h2 class="pt-2">{{ $product->title }}</h2>
        <h6 class="pt-2">Stars - Numbers of reviews | Microsoft</h6>
        <h1 style="font-weight:bold; font-size:30px" class="pt-2">${{ $product->price }}</h1>
        <h6 style="font-weight:bold" class="pt-2">Free 2-day shipping </h6>
        <hr>
        <div class="product-sell product">
            <h6 class="text-muted">Qty :</h6>
            <select name="quantity" id="qty" class="mr-2">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
            </select>
            <button class="rounded btn btn-primary" type="submit" form="NoForm" value="Submit">Add to <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="product-shipping">
            <h5 style="font-size:17px; font-weight:bold"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane mr-2"></i>Sale & shipping by Some-Brand</h5>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="wish-list">
            <h6 style="font-weight:bold">Save it too...</h6><button class="rounded btn btn-primary" type="submit" form="NoForm" value="Submit">Add to <i class="fas fa-heart"></i></button>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="form error-form">
            <h6 class="" style="font-weight:bold">Contact us</h6>
            <a class="text-dark" href=""><i class="fas fa-comment mr-2"></i><u>Let us know if something went wrong</u></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr class="mt-5">
<div class="text-center pt-5">
    <div class="container">
        <h3 class="text-left">Other customers looked for</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item row no-gutters active offset-md-1">
                <div class="card col-3 float-left mr-5" style="width: 200px;"><a href="{{ route('welcome.show', ['product' => $product]) }}"><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ $product->imageUrl }}" alt="Card image cap"></a><div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title">{{ $product->title}}</h5><h2 class="card-text">${{ $product->price }}</h2></div></div>
                <div class="card col-3 float-left mr-5" style="width: 200px;"><a href="{{ route('welcome.show', ['product' => $product]) }}"><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ $product->imageUrl }}" alt="Card image cap"></a><div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title">{{ $product->title}}</h5><h2 class="card-text">${{ $product->price }}</h2></div></div>
                <div class="card col-3 float-left mr-5" style="width: 200px;"><a href="{{ route('welcome.show', ['product' => $product]) }}"><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ $product->imageUrl }}" alt="Card image cap"></a><div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title">{{ $product->title}}</h5><h2 class="card-text">${{ $product->price }}</h2></div></div>
                <div class="card col-3 float-left mr-5" style="width: 200px;"><a href="{{ route('welcome.show', ['product' => $product]) }}"><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ $product->imageUrl }}" alt="Card image cap"></a><div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title">{{ $product->title}}</h5><h2 class="card-text">${{ $product->price }}</h2></div></div>
                <div class="card col-3 float-left mr-5" style="width: 200px;"><a href="{{ route('welcome.show', ['product' => $product]) }}"><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ $product->imageUrl }}" alt="Card image cap"></a><div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title">{{ $product->title}}</h5><h2 class="card-text">${{ $product->price }}</h2></div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item row no-gutters offset-md-1">
                <div class="card col-3 float-left mr-5" style="width: 200px;"><a href="{{ route('welcome.show', ['product' => $product]) }}"><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ $product->imageUrl }}" alt="Card image cap"></a><div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title">{{ $product->title}}</h5><h2 class="card-text">${{ $product->price }}</h2></div></div>
                <div class="card col-3 float-left mr-5" style="width: 200px;"><a href="{{ route('welcome.show', ['product' => $product]) }}"><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ $product->imageUrl }}" alt="Card image cap"></a><div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title">{{ $product->title}}</h5><h2 class="card-text">${{ $product->price }}</h2></div></div>
                <div class="card col-3 float-left mr-5" style="width: 200px;"><a href="{{ route('welcome.show', ['product' => $product]) }}"><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ $product->imageUrl }}" alt="Card image cap"></a><div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title">{{ $product->title}}</h5><h2 class="card-text">${{ $product->price }}</h2></div></div>
                <div class="card col-3 float-left mr-5" style="width: 200px;"><a href="{{ route('welcome.show', ['product' => $product]) }}"><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ $product->imageUrl }}" alt="Card image cap"></a><div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title">{{ $product->title}}</h5><h2 class="card-text">${{ $product->price }}</h2></div></div>
                <div class="card col-3 float-left mr-5" style="width: 200px;"><a href="{{ route('welcome.show', ['product' => $product]) }}"><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ $product->imageUrl }}" alt="Card image cap"></a><div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title">{{ $product->title}}</h5><h2 class="card-text">${{ $product->price }}</h2></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="pt-5">
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Product description</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <h6 class="text-left" style="font-size:20px">{{ $product->description }}</h6>
    </div>
</div>
<hr class="mt-5">
<div class="text-center pt-5">
    <div class="container">
        <h3 class="text-left">Other customers bought</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item row no-gutters active offset-md-1">
                <div class="card col-3 float-left mr-5" style="width: 200px;"><a href="{{ route('welcome.show', ['product' => $product]) }}"><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ $product->imageUrl }}" alt="Card image cap"></a><div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title">{{ $product->title}}</h5><h2 class="card-text">${{ $product->price }}</h2></div></div>
                <div class="card col-3 float-left mr-5" style="width: 200px;"><a href="{{ route('welcome.show', ['product' => $product]) }}"><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ $product->imageUrl }}" alt="Card image cap"></a><div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title">{{ $product->title}}</h5><h2 class="card-text">${{ $product->price }}</h2></div></div>
                <div class="card col-3 float-left mr-5" style="width: 200px;"><a href="{{ route('welcome.show', ['product' => $product]) }}"><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ $product->imageUrl }}" alt="Card image cap"></a><div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title">{{ $product->title}}</h5><h2 class="card-text">${{ $product->price }}</h2></div></div>
                <div class="card col-3 float-left mr-5" style="width: 200px;"><a href="{{ route('welcome.show', ['product' => $product]) }}"><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ $product->imageUrl }}" alt="Card image cap"></a><div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title">{{ $product->title}}</h5><h2 class="card-text">${{ $product->price }}</h2></div></div>
                <div class="card col-3 float-left mr-5" style="width: 200px;"><a href="{{ route('welcome.show', ['product' => $product]) }}"><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ $product->imageUrl }}" alt="Card image cap"></a><div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title">{{ $product->title}}</h5><h2 class="card-text">${{ $product->price }}</h2></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr class="mt-5">
<div class="container">
    <div class="comments">
        <h3>Reviews and comments</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" id="app">
            <star-rating></star-rating>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            Rating - statistics
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @if(auth()->check())
                <div class="create-review text-right">
                    <a href="{{ route('create.review', [$product] ) }}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" style="border-radius:20px">Write a review</a>
                </div>
            @else
                <div class="write-review text-right">
                    <a href="/login" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" style="border-radius:20px">Write a review</a>
                </div>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>Recent comments</h3>
            @forelse($product->reviews as $review)
            <div class="comment mt-5 border border-dark pl-3 pt-3 pb-3 mb-3 rounded">
                <div class="title">
                    <h4>{{ $review->headline }}</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="body-text pt-3 pr-5">
                    <p style="text-align:justify"><strong>{{ $review->description }}</strong></p>
                </div>
                <div class="author pt-2">
                    <h6 class="text-muted">{{ $review->user_name }},  {{ date('d-m-Y', strtotime( $review->created_at )) }}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="votes row">

                </div>
            </div>
            @empty
            <h6>There are not reviews for this product</h6>
            @endforelse
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection

@section('scripts')
<script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

This is my "resources/assets/js/app.js", where I have the Vue Component.

**App.js**

```
import VueStarRating from 'vue-star-rating'

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');



Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

Vue.component('star-rating', VueStarRating);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

This is **my webpack.mix.js**

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

And finally, this is my layout file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>@yield('title')</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::to('src/css/app.css') }}">
    @yield('styles')
</head>
<body>
@include('partials.header')
@yield('content')
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-SlE991lGASHoBfWbelyBPLsUlwY1GwNDJo3jSJO04KZ33K2bwfV9YBauFfnzvynJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
@yield('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? Every kind of help is welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: I ran into a very similar issue a couple of days ago which took me a good while to get my head around. The issue was caused by jQuery being loaded in twice - once by Laravel Vue, and once by me in my base View. Could you confirm whether any of bootstrap's assets are being loaded in twice?

Comment: @AdamThomason, you're right, I just deleted the jQuery script from my layout and changed it for the js/app.js file, and now everything is working well. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed my jQuery scripts which are in the layouts.app and changed it for the file js/app.js. Now, everything is working right. 
What I was doing is repeating the scripts of jQuery and it was creating a problem when I was using Bootstrap on a view.

Thanks to @Adam Thomason for his help.